# Angular two different types with this name exist

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am facing with this problem at Angular app, in other folders this is working just here not it is showing me this message.

```
Type 'Map<string, Person>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, Person>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
```

Here is the code

```
persons: Map<string, Person>;

store.select('rodex').subscribe(rodex => {
      this.persons = rodex.persons;
    });
```

Comment: What do you import into the typescript file? Is it possible that the structure of 'Person' varies from file to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable declared

From

```
persons: Map<string, Person>;
```

To

```
persons = Map<string, Person>();
```

and import Map like this

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
```